# Efficiently Joining and Transforming Data in PySpark DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, dictionary, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks-sql

**Description:**

I'm working with PySpark 3.4 and have a DataFrame (df) with two columns: **key_value_pair** and **version**. The key_value_pair column is a map containing key-value pairs, and the version column is a string indicating the version of the data.

**DataFrame df:**

| key_value_pair | version |
| --- | --- |
| {"blueberry": "1", "banana": "20", "grape": "161", "orange": "gh", "cherry": "1.50", "apple": "a", "kiwi": "0", "pear": "z", "melon": "0", "strawberry": "1"} | v1 |

I also have a reference DataFrame (df_ref) with columns id, datatype, and version. This DataFrame provides information about the data types of the keys and corresponds to a specific version:

**DataFrame df_ref:**

| id | datatype | version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | str | v1 |
| pear | str | v1 |
| orange | str | v1 |
| grape | double | v1 |
| banana | double | v1 |
| cherry | double | v1 |
| kiwi | bool | v1 |

**Objective:**

1. Efficiently join these two DataFrames based on the conditions:

   - key_value_pair.key = df_ref.id
   - version = df_ref.version
2. Create a new column (col_join) that combines key_value_pair.key, key_value_pair.value, and  df_ref.datatype into a new map.
3. Based on col_join, create three new MapType columns (col_str, col_bool, col_double) with the following schemas:

- col_str: MapType(StringType, StringType)
- col_bool: MapType(StringType, BooleanType)
- col_double: MapType(StringType, DoubleType)

For example, if the key is "apple", value is "a", and datatype is "str", then col_str should have a map like {"apple": "a"}.

**col_join** could take the following structure; however, this column is eventually dropped, so its specific appearance is not critical as long as it facilitates the creation of the three required columns.

| col_join |
| --- |
| {"apple": ["a", "str"], "pear": ["z", "str"], "orange": ["gh", "str"], "grape": ["161", "double"], "banana": ["20", "double"], "cherry": ["1.50", "double"], "kiwi": ["0", "bool"], "melon": ["0", "bool"], "strawberry": ["1", "bool"], "blueberry": ["1", "bool"]} |

One of the 3 needed columns is **col_str** and that should look as follows:

| col_str |
| --- |
| {"apple": "a", "pear": "z", "orange": "gh"} |

**Questions:**

1. Is there a more efficient way to perform this join and transformation without using explode or UDF?
2. Are there any best practices I should consider for optimizing the performance of this operation in PySpark?
3. How can I further improve the creation of col_str, col_bool, and col_double based on the col_join column?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thank you in advance!

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, map_from_arrays, broadcast, col, map_filter, transform_keys, when, lit

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

# Example data
data = ({"apple": "a", "pear": "z", "orange": "gh", "grape": "161", "banana": "20", "cherry": "1.50", "kiwi": "0", "melon": "0", "strawberry": "1", "blueberry": "1"},
        "v1")

# Example data reference table
df_list_data = [("apple", "str", "v1"), ("pear", "str", "v1"), ("orange", "str", "v1"), ("grape", "double", "v1"),
                ("banana", "double", "v1"), ("cherry", "double", "v1"), ("kiwi", "bool", "v1"), ("melon", "bool", "v1"),
                ("strawberry", "bool", "v1"), ("blueberry", "bool", "v1")]

# Column names
columns = ["key_value_pair", "version"]  # Added a missing comma

# Column names ref
columns_ref = ["id", "datatype", "version"]

# Create a Spark DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame([data], columns)  # Wrapped 'data' in a list

# Create a Spark DataFrame ref
df_ref = spark.createDataFrame(df_list_data, columns_ref)
```

I tried differend high-order functions, but I did not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Your task involves efficiently joining two PySpark DataFrames and transforming the data according to specified conditions. To optimize this process while avoiding the use of explode or UDFs (User-Defined Functions), you can leverage PySpark's built-in DataFrame operations and higher-order functions. Here's a strategy to accomplish your objectives:

## Step 1: Join DataFrames

First, join df and df_ref on the conditions specified. Since PySpark 3.0, you can use the higher-order function transform_keys to work with map types. This might be a more efficient approach than using explode, which can be expensive in terms of performance as it can significantly increase the number of rows.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

# Join the dataframes
joined_df = df.join(broadcast(df_ref), expr("key_value_pair[key] = id AND version = df_ref.version"))
```

## Step 2: Create col_join

Now, create col_join by combining the key, value, and datatype. You can use transform_keys here:

```
joined_df = joined_df.withColumn("col_join", expr("transform_keys(key_value_pair, (k, v) -> map(k, array(v, datatype)))"))
```

## Step 3: Create col_str, col_bool, col_double

For the creation of col_str, col_bool, and col_double, you need to filter and cast values based on the datatype. Here, map_filter can be used:

```
joined_df = joined_df.withColumn("col_str", map_filter("col_join", lambda k, v: v[1] == 'str'))
joined_df = joined_df.withColumn("col_bool", map_filter("col_join", lambda k, v: v[1] == 'bool'))
joined_df = joined_df.withColumn("col_double", map_filter("col_join", lambda k, v: v[1] == 'double'))
```

## Optimizing Performance

1. Avoid Shuffles: Use broadcast joins wherever possible, especially if
   one DataFrame is significantly smaller than the other.
2. Partitioning: Ensure your data is partitioned effectively across the
   cluster to optimize parallel processing.
3. Caching: If you're reusing intermediate results multiple times,
   consider caching them.
4. Avoid explode: As you've already mentioned, try to avoid explode as
   it can increase the data volume and decrease performance.
5. Use higher-order functions: Functions like transform_keys and
   map_filter are more efficient than UDFs.
6. Lazy Evaluation: Remember that Spark uses lazy evaluation. Design
   your transformations keeping that in mind to optimize the execution plan.

## Further Improvements

To further improve the creation of col_str, col_bool, and col_double, consider if there are ways to simplify the transform_keys logic or if additional Spark functions could be leveraged for more efficiency.

Keep an eye on the Spark UI to monitor the performance and see where potential bottlenecks might be.

This approach should give you a good starting point. Depending on your specific data and cluster configuration, further tuning might be necessary.

Comment: Thanks Anouar, but this code does not work.. Attempting a different approach now by creating a Python dictionary from df_ref
# Collect data from df_ref
mapping_data = df_ref.collect()

# Convert the collected data to a Python dictionary
mapping_dict = {row['id']: {'datatype': row['datatype'], 'version': row['version']} for row in mapping_data}

# Broadcasting the created mapping dictionary to be used in Spark transformations
broadcasted_mapping_dict = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(mapping_dict)
Did not succeed yet.